# How do I arrive at a general solution to this simple differential equation by using integration only?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is:
$$A\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + Bx = 0$$
where $A, B > 0$

Although it's a fairly simple differential equation but I wanted to solve it through integration by change of variables. I did my following efforts:
We can think of it as $x$ is displacement and $t$ is time. So,
$$
A\frac{vdv}{dx} = -Bx\\
v = ±\sqrt{-kx^2+c_1/A}
$$
where $k = B/A$ and $c_1$ is the constant of integration.
$$
±\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-kx^2+c_1/A}} = dt\\
±\frac{dx}{i\sqrt{k}\sqrt{x^2-\frac{c_1}{B}}} = dt
$$
Now the problem which arises here is that doing trigonometric substitution for $x$ would mean we are assuming $x$ to be real. And indeed on proceeding further, we do get $x$ to be real. But since we want a general solution for the above differential equation, how can I proceed further?

Comment: $v*\frac{dv}{dx}\ne \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ so you can not do this .

Comment: @trula But why?

Comment: Before you make the $v=\pm\sqrt{\dots}$ you should already get $c_1/A>0$ and bound on $x$.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you please clarify more on "bound of $x$"

Comment: to your question to me ; how do you derive $∗\frac{}{}= \frac{_2}{^2}$

Comment: @trula $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d(\frac{dx}{dt})}{dt}.\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{vdv}{dx}$ That's a basic physics formula.

Answer (score 1):

From

$$
A\ddot x+Bx=0\Rightarrow A\ddot x\dot x+Bx\dot x=0\Rightarrow A\dot x^2+Bx^2= C
$$

so

$$
\frac AC\dot x^2+\frac BC x^2 = 1\Rightarrow \left(\frac {\dot x}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac {x}{b}\right)^2= 1
$$

thus

$$
x = b \sin \left(\frac{a t}{b}+c_1\right)
$$

NOTE

From the initial conditions we have $C = A\dot x_0^2+B x_0^2$ which is a generic constant, and the other (should be two of them) is $c_1$.

Comment: But this isn't the general solution.

Comment: Yes, it is. It has two arbitrary constants: $c_1$ and $b\,(=C/B)$. (Notice that, although $b$ is arbitrary, $a/b\,(=B/A)$ is not.)